# Issue inserting data into SQL Server database using PyODBC

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am getting data from .xlsx files and storing it into a SQL Server database using *execute* command. Occacionally, neither the data is inserted into database nor an exception occurred. So it seems to be everything right but I got some data missed. I am using the following code:

```
    cursor.execute("""IF OBJECT_ID('Vibraciones.dbo.{tab}') IS NULL
                  CREATE TABLE Vibraciones.dbo.{tab} (SAP int, Equipo nvarchar(MAX), Estado nchar(10), Aviso int, Fecha nvarchar(50), Condicion nchar(10), Observaciones nvarchar(MAX))""".format(tab=table_name))
                   
    cnxn.commit()

    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {tab} (SAP,Equipo,Estado,Aviso,Fecha,Condicion,Observaciones) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)".format(tab=table_name), row.SAP, row.Equipo, row.Estado, row.Aviso, row.Fecha, row.Condición, row.Observaciones)
            
        except Exception as e: print(e)
            
    cnxn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Bad dynamic statement? Your statements are open to injection attacks, afterall.

Comment: _Any idea what the problem_ The most likely explanation is a bug in your code that goes unreported. You need better instrumentation in your code (like a "verbose mode") to debug problems of this nature. Perhaps df2 has no rows? And I have to question why an application needs to create a permanent table in a database - one of any name but a fixed set of columns. And use of 3-part names is a bad habit - the connection should determine the database in which your objects are located. That just might be your problem - you create a table in one database but you insert into a different database

Comment: Both answer are right. I am giving my firts steps creating databases and I merged different codes. I am going to keep your advices in mind. I could solve the problem commiting after every "execute" inside de for loop. Thank you very much!!